# foundation add shopping cart total

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to display a shopping cart total in the foundation top bar. at the moment I have the code below.
The cart total is displayed as a total on large screens but a menu on smaller ones.
Is there a way to override the top section so the cart total always displays and does not become a menu on smaller devices.
Thanks

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
    <ul class="title-area">

       <li class="name">
          <h1><a href="#">Top Bar Title</a></h1>
       </li>
       <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
          <a href="#"><span>menu</span></a>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="left">
           <li>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="right">

          <!-- ################## -->
          <li>
             <?php echo $cart; ?>
          </li>

       </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you could move your cart outside of the ul.right and .top-bar-section? if so, then it's pretty easy to set position absolute to it and stick it to the right at every resolution.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/d6g6fbyo/1/][1]
```

Regarding the question itself whether it's possible to keep the cart on every screen with the current markup only overwriting some styles, i really doubt so.

In small resolutions .top-bar-section wraps onto the next line while the .top-bar loses his overflow:visible, that results in that one will never see the contents of .top-bar-section, unless javascript will toggle back overflow:visible. thus it makes impossible to position the cart back to visibility inside that unhappy .top-bar-section.